# How to synchronize datetime in a webapp with the sytem datetime in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: java, shell, datetime, tomcat6, ubuntu-12.04

We are working on a web app implemented using jsp/servlets and currently we are using ubuntu 12.04 server. We need to add another UI which allows users to change Ubuntu system datetime.  It would have the same functionality which can be seen in webmin tools.
In this case what would you suggest for the application design is to be ?

1. How to synchronize webapp datetime at client side with the the system date time ?  So the web UI gets updated automatically in every 5 sec. What Its design will look like..
2. How This can be done in java, synchronize or at least to modify system datetime. Do I have to use shell scripts for this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be resolved adopting to a simple design where client side is handled by jqueries and use of java scripts, in the update shell commands used to upgrade the system data.